# Python oauth/flask, how to pass arguments from decorated function

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators, flask-oauthlib

I need to call the method of @oauth.token_handler internally from flask.
The signature is as follow:

```
@oauth.token_handler
def access_token(*args, **kwargs):
    return None
```

So it calls internally the implementation of token_handler().
I try to call

```
response = access_token("", {'grant_type':'password'})
```

Wishing that oauth can retrieve the arguments in the method, but it doesn't work.

```
400 {"error": "unsupported_grant_type"}
```

Oauth don't find the data (without surprise for me)

When a curl method work as expected:

```
curl -k -X POST -d "client_id=f9O7kapzXnK1gYAxxxxxxx&grant_type=password&username=blah&password=pass" http://localhost:5001/oauth/token
```

My question is, how to fake this call to oauth internally in order that it can retrieve all the information (grant_type, client_id, etc...). Because for the moment, I tryed with no luck.

Note: I know oauth should be called from the client side; But here, the process is that a person send me his/her provider credential for his/her id profil, I check if the credential is ok, and then I create an internal account with my own oauth provider and send them the access_token to the ressource of my application. 
My problem here is that I don't know how to call access_token() with the right parameter. Flask-oauth can't find my arguments.

Doc can be found here:
 http://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Flask-OAuthlib. I have to say, it is not well designed, I strongly suggest that you use [Authlib](https://github.com/lepture/authlib). Here is an [example of OAuth 2 provider](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server).